# word2vec check next/prev word probability

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

While using word2vec, if the current word is `US` or `monday`, how can I check that word `the` has a high probability to come before `US`; and `next` has a common occurrence before the word `monday`, and so on and so forth?

Comment: arent these just bi-grams? you can extract probabilities of bi-grams with a specific corpus. is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

While word2vec uses the exercise of predicting words to train its word-vectors, it is not really a tool for making such predictions. During training, such precise probabilities of likely paired-words aren't formed, and after training such probabilities can't be read/calculated from the final word-vectors.

You may want to just create your own raw counts of word co-occurrences – rather than word2vec's dense word embeddings – and use those raw counts to make your judgements about likely word predecessors/successors.